# Сумма первых трёх цифр номера равна сумме последних трёх цифр

Tags: java, алгоритм

Как составить алгоритм по заданию или блок-схему?

Задание:

> В городе N проезд в трамвае осуществляется по бумажным отрывным билетам. Каждую неделю трамвайное депо заказывает в местной типографии рулон билетов с номерами от 000001 до 999999. «Счастливым» считается билетик у которого сумма первых трёх цифр номера равна сумме последних трёх цифр, как, например, в билетах с номерами 003102 или 567576. Трамвайное депо решило подарить сувенир обладателю каждого счастливого билета и теперь раздумывает, как много сувениров потребуется. С помощью программы подсчитайте сколько счастливых билетов в одном рулоне?

Comment: представление трех значного числа (в десятичной системе исчесления): 100 * a + 10 * b + c; где a,b,c цифры из которого оно состоит.

Comment: А вы пробовали подставить хотя бы к примеру к этим двум написанным кодам число 003102 и проверить сумма станет 1 или так и останется 0 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот например, очень полно [Счастливые Билеты](http://www.ega-math.narod.ru/Quant/Tickets.htm)

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(55252);
} // main
```

Comment: мне особенно понравился код :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Task13 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 000001; i <= 999999; i++){
            int number1 = i/100000;
            int number2 = (i/10000)%10;
            int number3 = (i/1000)%10%10;
            int number4 = (i/100)%10%10%10;
            int number5 = (i/10)%10%10%10%10;
            int number6 = i%10%10%10%10;

            if(number1 + number2 + number3 == number4 + number5 + number6){
                sum++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Рулон билетов с номерами от 000001 до 999999 имеет " + sum + " счастливых билетов.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Операция взятия остатка (%) является идемпотентной.

Comment: `%10%10%10%10` - что это за адъ?

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас вот тоже эту программу пишу по учёбе и что-то не понял как вы вообще догадались строить такие многоэтажки. Вы нецелое число записываете в int, то бишь оно преобразуется в целое. 123456/1000 = 123,456 это да. Но если вы запишите int num = 123456/1000, то num будет равно 123. то бишь только целой части, и тогда чтобы получить остаток нужно будет просто сделать один % 123%10=3 и так далее. Так что тут должно быть так:

```
    int sum=0;
    System.out.println("Third program");
    for (int i = 1; i < 999999; i++)
    {
        int num1=i/100000;
        //первое число
        int num2=(i/10000)%10;
        //второе число
        int num3=(i/1000)%10;
        //
        int num4=(i/100)%10;
        //
        int num5=(i/10)%10;
        //
        int num6=i%10;
    }
```

Comment: вопрос вообще-то был про алгоритм. а в вашем ответе такая информация напрочь отсуствует.

Comment: согласен, но тут в комментариях явно о другом. Поэтому добавил, может поможет кому

Answer (score -2):

Я вот так это же задание записал, да бы не играть с этими остатками от деления остатков от деления)) Но спасибо за ваш вариант, он помог мне перестать тупить с этой задачей.

```
    int sum = 0;
    for(int k = 000001; k <= 999999; k++){
        int number1 = k/100000;
        int number2 = (k%100000)/10000;
        int number3 = (k%10000)/1000;
        int number4 = (k%1000)/100;
        int number5 = (k%100)/10;
        int number6 = k%10;        

        if(number1 + number2 + number3 == number4 + number5 + number6){
            sum++;
            }                
        }
    System.out.println( sum + " счастливых билетов.");
    }
```